# Adding to a Generic List with Type parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, types, reflection

Consider the following setup:

```
using System;

class Shelf : ScriptableObject // << IS A SCRIPTABLE OBJECT
{
    [SerializeField] List<Jars> jars = new();

    public AddUniqueJar(Type typeOfJar)
    {
        //need to add a new object of type typeOfJar to jars. I currently do something like this:
       sentences.Add((Jar)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfJar));
       EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
       AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
       AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }
}
[Serializable]
abstract class Jar// << NOT A SCRIPTABLE OBJECT

[Serializable]
class JamJar:Jar{}

[Serializable]
class PickleJar:Jar{}

[Serializable]
class MoneyJar:Jar{}
```

I'd have imagined this would all be fine -, when the editor adds to the list the listview shows my new entry - but the next time my code compiles or restart a session my object loses the data for what is stored in the `jars` List and the ListView that queries it reports it as an empty list.

How do I get my method to add a new object of this type to the list while also serializing and maintaining that information between sessions?

Comment: Add `[SerializeField]` attribute to jars, or make it public.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Appreciate it, but it didn't work. `jars` did initially have the `[SerializeField]` property. But this doesn't change the issue I'm having with the null references.

Comment: When are you calling the function AddUniqueJar?  Does it happen from a custom editor/editor window, or while the game is running?

Comment: A custom editor window, while I'm in the editor. I know it is passing the right type as debug breakpoint in the method is showing me the right type.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "forgets." Is there data retrieval code somewhere that isn't working? Can you share it?

Comment: It sounds like those assets do not exist in the asset database.  You likely need to use AssetDatabase.CreateAsset in order for those instances to be tracked, since they inherit Object.

Comment: Yes, @JohnWu I have a custom editor for `Shelf` assets. It looks at a given `Shelf` and makes a `UIElements.ListView` of every instance of a `Jar` in the `Shelf` object in question.
The `ListView.itemsSource` is the `jars` List from the current `Shelf` object considered and each item shows what type of `Jar` it is. I have a button to add a unique `Jar` object to the considered `Shelf` and this shows said `Jar` in the list as expected but the next session (reopening unity or recompiling code) I start, the title showin the `Jar` type is gone and I get a null reference.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Following your advice, I didn't realise `UnityEngine.Object` was asset-oriented. All my classes are now just `System.Object` derived. I have also added the `Serializable` attribute to them. I am no longer getting null references but when I start a new session or recompile, the list shows as empty.

Comment: @DanielFamakin I think there is some confusion here. As far as I know, data that is stored in in-memory variables is wiped clean when the process exits and reinitialized (e.g. to an empty list) when you start the program. If you want to persist data, you have to write code to do it, e.g. save the data to a database or flat file, then read the data back when the program starts. Is this your understanding as well? If so, how are you reading the data back?

Comment: @JohnWu perhaps I have misunderstood what `ScriptableObject` files do. I was under the assumption that they are an alternative to converting data to and from JSON and other similar formats to allow users to store things like player save data, or level editing data between sessions. Is this not the case, if so, I apologise

Comment: @JohnWu "Data that you save from Editor Tools to ScriptableObjects as an asset is written to disk and is therefore persistent between sessions." From "https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html"

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work this way!

The [Serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) doesn't serialize custom `abstract` types - seems to be missing in the documentation though to be fair.

---

Anyway, even if the serializer **would** serialize `abstract` types then it still only sees and knows the type `Jar` -> it would anyway only serialize the values of a `Jar` and trying to deserialize into instances of `Jar`.

---

I think closest you will come to your use case would be to indeed convert those to `ScriptableObject` and have

```
class Shelf : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] List<Jar> jars = new();

    public void AddUniqueJar<T>() where T : Jar
    {
        var newjar = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>();
        newJar.name = $"New {typeof(T).Name}";
        jars.Add(newjar);
        AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(newjar, this);
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }
}

abstract class Jar : ScriptableObject { }

class JamJar : Jar { }

class PickleJar : Jar { }

class MoneyJar : Jar { }
```

To directly store those within the same asset.

Little demo:

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Shelf : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] List<Jar> jars = new();

    public void AddUniqueJar<T>() where T : Jar
    {
        var newJar = CreateInstance<T>();
        newJar.name = $"New {typeof(T).Name}";
        jars.Add(newJar);
        AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(newJar, this);
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty(this);
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }

    [ContextMenu(nameof(AddMoneyJar))]
    private void AddMoneyJar()
    {
        AddUniqueJar<MoneyJar>();
    }

    [ContextMenu(nameof(AddPickleJar))]
    private void AddPickleJar()
    {
        AddUniqueJar<PickleJar>();
    }

    [ContextMenu(nameof(AddJamJar))]
    private void AddJamJar()
    {
        AddUniqueJar<JamJar>();
    }
}
```

[image]

Personally I would even rather save those as separate assets so you can easily maintain, remove them etc.

---

Or alternatively if it is really only about having different instance types you could also just instead serialize a list of an `enum` or type name and then rather on runtime create the instances of those accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Jar classes are not serializing is because Jar is abstract.
After removing the abstract keyword, all classes are serializing like usual.

You should remove the EditorUtility and AssetDatabase code from the scriptable object, as it is not needed for this serialization to occur.

Comment: I will try this out, does this mean that unity will not serialize children of abstract classes? I don't want any instances of `Jar` but rather instances of subclasses of `Jar`, hence it is abstract.

Comment: Okay I've put it through and it has maintained the list contents but now the type of the list on recompile is just `Jar` which is what I was seeking to avoid with polymorphism.

Comment: I believe the reason is because Jar is abstract and an instance of it cannot be created, having the list of that type means unity cannot create the instances.  If the list was of a concrete type, that might be a different story when it comes down to the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Jar being abstract is the reason it was null referencing but simply making it a concrete class is not a solution as now any instances of `Jar`-derived classes are showing as instances of `Jar` instead.